# Grails: How to use @BindUsing for an attribute with belongsTo

Tags: grails

I have a domain object whose structure is like following -

`

```
class TaxPlan {

    String taxCode
    String description
    Double taxRate
    Timestamp dateCreated
    Timestamp lastUpdated

    static belongsTo = [location: Location]
}
```

I want to refine the "location" attribute to use bindUsing annotation. How do I do that? I want something like below code -

```
class TaxPlan {

    String taxCode
    String description
    Double taxRate
    Timestamp dateCreated
    Timestamp lastUpdated
    @BindUsing({
        obj, source ->

        Location.findByStoreNumber(source['location'])?:RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()?.session.location

    })
    static belongsTo = [location: Location]
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't use the `http-session` in your domain classes

Comment: thats not the issue, how do I use @bindUsing for location?